# How to apply an opacity filter to a cover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a "opacity filter" to a cover image with the class cover__filter but the text gets the opacity too.
I tried with z-index but it seems I can't fix it. Do you have some tips?

```
<section class="cover">
  <div class="cover__filter">
    <div class="cover__caption">
      <div class="cover__caption__copy">
        <h1>Primary message of the home</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
        <a href="" class="button">Call to action</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: mention the styles in the css classess used in the question

Comment: the thing is, that opacity is rendered last. Therefor it will cover up everything incl text and links. Links will become unclickable. Depending of what you try to do, the might be betetr methods like filter: blur; or transparency.

Comment: I found the problem. The closing tag was in the wrong position. The right one was " <div class="cover__filter">"